# Projecting points on a Pareto-front onto a (hyper)plane?

Tags: linear-algebra, genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

I'm trying to implement the Biased Crowding Distance in NSGA-II as described in the paper [Integrating User Preferences into Evolutionary Multi-Objective Optimization](https://www.iitk.ac.in/kangal/papers/k2004004.pdf) by Branke and Deb.

Basically, from what I understand, given a set of points on a Pareto-front, we need to project the points onto a hyperplane with a direction vector. Doing this will give the new crowding distance d' based on the locations of the individualson the hyperplane with a certain direction.

To illustrate, see the figure below.

[image: Biased crowding distance approach]

My question is simple: how do we obtain the hyperplane given a user-specified direction vector? Is it simply by getting the perpendicular of the direction vector?

Thanks and any information would be very helpful.